# System.FormatException is unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, exception, formatexception

I am sending my poolid in hdnfield when am converting it to show me error . poolid is `int32` datatype

```
 if (ddlStaticPoolName.Visible)
    {
        objUserEntity.POOLNAME = Convert.ToString(ddlStaticPoolName.SelectedItem.Text);
        objUserEntity.POOlID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlStaticPoolName.SelectedValue);
    }
    else if (lblDynamicPoolName.Visible)
    {
        objUserEntity.POOLNAME = Convert.ToString(lblDynamicPoolName.Text);
       objUserEntity.POOlID =Convert.ToInt32(hdnDynamicPoolID.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        objUserEntity.POOLNAME = "";
        objUserEntity.POOlID = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the example of string `ddlStaticPoolName.SelectedValue` that you are trying to convert to int32?

Comment: Which lines gives an error, in if or else-if, point it out please

Comment: Is SelectedValue empty string?

Comment: Converting empty string to `Int32` fails check this : `Convert.ToInt32("")`

Answer (score 0):

> If the string Contains numerical characters But its not Whole Number (ex: double , decimal).

```
objUserEntity.POOlID = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(ddlStaticPoolName.SelectedValue));
```

If the string contains double Number it Cant be directly converted to Int. If this not Solve your problem you must give an Example of `ddlStaticPoolName.SelectedValue`.

> If the string Contains Non numerical characters. Then you should use TryParse.

```
  int num;
  Int32.TryParse(ddlStaticPoolName.SelectedValue, out num);
  objUserEntity.POOlID = num;
```

If the string contains invalid number. TryParse will set the value of `num` to 0. otherwise to the value Converted from string.

If you try this solutions one of them must solve your problem. But Try First solution then go To the next solution.

Comment: thanks M.kazem  Akhgary for helping  second solution is helped me alot.